# how to draw lines simultaneously show x & y coordinators on top of mouse pointer using canvas and javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, mouseevent

draw lines while mouseDown and simultaneously show  x & y coordinators on top of mouse pointer while MouseMove using canvas and javascript.

Here x & y coordinators are continuously drawing on top of mouse pointer while MouseMove. Then I am unable Draw Lines while MouseDown since i am using ctxTemp.clearRect(0,0,canvasTemp.width,canvasTemp.height);

if i am not using ctxTemp.clearRect(0,0,canvasTemp.width,canvasTemp.height); then x & y coordinators are continuously drawing on top of mouse pointer while MouseMove.

thanks is advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Double buffer

It is a common task to render addition guides (coordinates, widgets, etc...) on the canvas while creating content.

Using a single canvas this become problematic as you are overwriting the content by clearing, or the just painting the guides .

The solution is to use an additional (or more) canvas to separate the content from the guides.

### Example

The example shows how this is done.

- A second canvas is created call `drawing`. It matches the size of the canvas on the page.
- The mouse draws the stroke to the second canvas.
- The main `update` function draws the second canvas onto the main canvas and then draws the mouse position in a box over that.
- As you can not draw outside the canvas some additional code is needed when drawing the mouse position to prevent it from going outside the canvas.

```js
requestAnimationFrame(update);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var w = canvas.width, h = canvas.height;
const drawing = createImage(w, h); // create canvas to hold drawing
const pointQueue = [];             // holds points when mouse button down
drawing.ctx.lineWidth = 4;
drawing.ctx.strokeStyle = "#F00";
drawing.ctx.lineJoin = "round";
drawing.ctx.lineCap = "round";
ctx.font = "16px Arial";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
/* add mouse listeners */
const bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
const mouse = {x: 0, y: 0, button: false}, events = ["down", "up", "move"];
events.forEach(name => document.addEventListener("mouse" + name, mouseEvents));
            
function drawMousePos(ctx) {
    const text = "X: " + mouse.x.toFixed(0) + " Y: " + mouse.y.toFixed(0);
    const width = ctx.measureText(text).width + 8;
    var x = mouse.x, y = mouse.y - 18;
    if (x + width / 2 > w) { x = w - width / 2 }
    if (x - width / 2 < 0) { x = width / 2 }
    if (y - 10  < 0) { y = 10 }
    if (y + 10  > h) { y = h - 10 }
    ctx.fillStyle = "#EEC8";
    ctx.fillRect(x - width / 2, y - 12, width , 20);
    ctx.strokeRect(x - width / 2, y - 12, width, 20);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000C";
    ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
}
function drawPen(ctx) {
    if (pointQueue.length >= 2) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(...pointQueue.shift());
        while (pointQueue.length > (mouse.button ? 1 : 0)) { ctx.lineTo(...pointQueue.shift()) }
        pointQueue.length && ctx.lineTo(...pointQueue[0]);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
function update(){
    if (pointQueue.length) {
        drawPen(drawing.ctx);        
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
        ctx.drawImage(drawing, 0, 0);
        pointQueue.length && drawMousePos(ctx);
        canvas.style.cursor = "none";
    } else { canvas.style.cursor = "crosshair" }
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
function createImage(w, h){
    const can = document.createElement("canvas");
    can.width = w;
    can.height = h;
    can.ctx = can.getContext("2d");
    return can;
}
function mouseEvents(e){
    mouse.x = e.pageX - bounds.left - 2;  // offset by 2 pixels for canvas border
    mouse.y = e.pageY - bounds.top - 2;
    if (e.type === "mousedown") { mouse.button = true } 
    if (mouse.button) { pointQueue.push([mouse.x , mouse.y]) }
    if (e.type === "mouseup") { mouse.button = false }
}
```

```css
canvas { 
    border : 2px solid black; 
    cursor: crosshair;
}
```

```html
Click drag mouse to draw<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width="512" height="256"></canvas>
```

Comment: its very useful but currently x&y coordinates are showing after mouseDown + mouseMove.  can u modify and help me with and make x & y coordinates while initial mouseMove only

Answer (score 0):

you could try binding a div or a span to your mouse and attach it an eventListener like 'mousemove', in this div you could have two spans like

```html
<div id='mouseCoord" style="position: absolute; top:0,left:0">
   <span id='mouseX'><span>
   <span id='mouseY'><span>
</div>
```

The div #mouseCoord would have an absolute position, and on mouse move, you could update his top/left position

```js
const mouseDiv = document.getElementById('mouseCoord')
const mouseX = document.getElementById('mouseX')
const mouseY = document.getElementById('mouseY')
mouseDiv.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  mouseDiv.setAttribute('style', `left: ${e.offsetX};top: ${e.offsetY}`)
  mouseY.innerText = `y: ${e.offsetY}`
  mouseY.innerText = `x: ${e.offsetX}`
})
```

With this in place, you could add some mouse events to control when you want to display the coordinate like only when the mouse is moving etc ...

I hope this can helps